# Materialize Select - doesn't work when dynamically adding option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

The second select tag doesn't not work when adding options elements dynamically. 
I know that I've to initialize material select for dynamic content but don't know how to do it.
I have attached my Java Script and Html tags for reference.

```js
 < script >

   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('select').material_select();
   }); < /script>
   
   <script type="text/javascript">
function populate(s1,s2){
 var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
 var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
 s2.innerHTML = "";
 if(s1.value == "Arsenal"){
  var optionArray = ["Mikel|John Obi Mikel"];
 } 
 for(var option in optionArray){
  var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
  var newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.value = pair[0];
  newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
  s2.options.add(newOption);
 }
}
</script >
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onChange="populate('slct1','slct2')">
    <option value="">Choose team</option>
    <option value="1">Arsenal</option>
    <option value="2">Chelsea</option>
    <option value="3">Manchester United</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select id="slct2" name="slct2">

  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you should not use pure Javascript's `document.getElementById`, `document.createElement`, `innerHTML` and etc...

Look at this complete sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                $('#teams').change(function() {

                    var 
                        selectedValue = $('#teams').val(),
                        dataSource,
                        i;

                    if (selectedValue === '1') {

                        dataSource = ['Mikel', 'Obi', 'Mikel'];
                    }
                    else if (selectedValue === '2') {

                        dataSource = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'];
                    }

                    $('#players').html('');

                    for (i in dataSource) {

                        $('#players').append('<option>' + dataSource[i] +'</option>');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="teams">
        <option value="">Choose team</option>
        <option value="1">Arsenal</option>
        <option value="2">Chelsea</option>
        <option value="3">Manchester United</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="players">
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/logual/kk6dag8j/

Updated HTML code with "Materialize" imports:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                $('#teams').change(function() {

                    var 
                        selectedValue = $('#teams').val(),
                        dataSource,
                        i;

                    if (selectedValue === '1') {

                        dataSource = ['Mikel', 'Obi', 'Mikel'];
                    }
                    else if (selectedValue === '2') {

                        dataSource = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'];
                    }

                    $('#players').html('');

                    for (i in dataSource) {

                        $('#players').append('<option>' + dataSource[i] +'</option>');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="input-field">
            <select style="display: block; width: 200px;" id="teams">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose team</option>
            <option value="1">Arsenal</option>
            <option value="2">Chelsea</option>
            <option value="3">Manchester United</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
            <select style="display: block; width: 200px;" id="players">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will this code work with Materialize imports without initializing again?

Comment: You can check it by yourself. Copy&Paste this code to your project, and you'll see the result.

Comment: Sorry, but it's doesn't work with Materialize imports while it's working perfectly fine without materialize imports.

Comment: Which imports? materialize.css and materialize.js?

Comment: YES.<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

Comment: There is no problem with my html code or JS code. Materialize framework hides all standard html form elements... I have made an update. Please look at my answer again

Comment: Really appreciate your help and keen interest Sir, the code as well the select dropdown is working fine but browser default select dropdown is being displayed instead of materialize UI.

Answer (score 0):

```js
     < script >

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').material_select();
        $('#slct1').change(function() {
          if ($('#slct1').val() == "1") {

            var a = " <select id='second_menu' >" <? php
            while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
              +"<option value='<?php echo $row1["
            player_id "];?>'><?php echo $row1["
            player_name "]; ?></option>" <? php endwhile; ?>
            +"</select>";
          } else if ($('#slct1').val() == "2") {

            var a = " <select id='second_menu' >" <? php
            while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
              +"<option value='<?php echo $row1["
            player_id "];?>'><?php echo $row1["
            player_name "]; ?></option>" <? php endwhile; ?>
            +"</select>";
          } else if ($('#slct1').val() == "3") {

            var a = " <select id='second_menu' >" <? php
            while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
              +"<option value='<?php echo $row1["
            player_id "];?>'><?php echo $row1["
            player_name "]; ?></option>" <? php endwhile; ?>
            +"</select>";
          }

          $("#set_options").html(a);

          $('#second_menu').material_select();
        })
      });
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select id="slct1" name="slct1">
    <option value="">Choose team</option>
    <option value="1">Arsenal</option>
    <option value="2">Chelsea</option>
    <option value="3">Manchester United</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="set_options"></div>
```

I found a solution myself by initializing the material select when adding dynamic option to it.

Comment: This is the correct answer for this query and this solution works for materialize. Pay attention to the $('#...') - include the hash otherwise it won't work properly.